# Posting to Facebook through a Multi user Saas

Tags: facebook

Developing a CRM Saas that will allow for user to sign in and manage their clients. What I would like to offer them is the ability to post comments from our CRM to their Facebook wall. Either in a separate "Facebook" section or on their dashboard.

How do I go about giving each user the ability to add their Facebook wall to or application. Somehow they have to give us permission or add the permissions to our system and we have store those permissions for each individual user(tied in by their log in info)

Do I need to develop an App with the Facebook API or is there something our there right now?

We have around 500 users right now and we want to make this implementation as smooth as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to register a Facebook App with Facebook to get a API ID and Secret you can use to access the API. You will need to use Facebook Connect to get the user to login to your website and then save the access_token and user_id to your database so you know who each user is, and which facebook account they own.

You can follow the Facebook Authentication guide and then read up on publishing stuff to Facebook Walls and Pages.

Can't be more specific since the answer would involve a lot of code and explaining. Something you should learn instead.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Not looking for coding but general implementation process and if it can be done for each registered user individually. More on the the steps necessary to get it accomplished.